# How to struture coroutine code without suspend function

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I have a method called `saveAccount`

```
fun saveAccount(id: Int, newName: String): Account {
    val encryptedNames: List<String> = repository.findNamesById(id)
    val decryptedNames: List<String> = encryptedNames.map { cryptographyService.decrypt(it) }

    if(decryptedNames.contains(newName))
        throw IllegalStateException()

    return repository.save(newName)
}
```

I want to concurrently decrypt all names, so I did:

```
suspend fun saveAccount(id: Int, newName: String): Account {
    val encryptedNames: List<String> = repository.findNamesById(id)

    val decryptedNames: List<String> = encryptedNames.map { 
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
            cryptographyService.decrypt(it) 
        } 
    }.awaitAll()

    if(decryptedNames.contains(newName))
        throw IllegalStateException()

    return repository.save(newName)
}
```

Until now everything is fine, but the question is: I can't make `saveAccount` a suspend function. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to decrypt each name in a separate coroutine, but `saveAccount` should only return when all decryption is done.

You can use [`runBlocking`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) for that:

```
fun saveAccount(id: Int, newName: String): Account {
    // ...
    val decryptedNames = runBlocking {
        encryptedNames.map {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
                cryptographyService.decrypt(it) 
            }
        }.awaitAll()
    }
    // ...
}
```

This way `saveAccount` does not have to be a `suspend` function.